# Boolean masks for stratification in Python like in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I want to create a boolean mask (n x p) to stratify values from a (n x 1) vector (eg, time series data) within bins of a (1 x p) vector. I use this result to retrieve and aggregate data on other (n x 1) vectors.

Here is my working code in Matlab:

```
function [histVar1]=histo(VecIn, ThreshLow, Var1)

     % VecIn: n x 1
     % Var1: n x 1
     % ThreshLow: 1 x p

     % create upper limits
     ThreshUp = [ThreshLow(2:end) 1e5];

     % create n x p boolean mask
     mask = VecIn>=ThreshLow & VecIn<ThreshUp;

     % use mask to retrieve p x 1 array /w aggregated values
     histVar1=sum(Var1(mask));
```

I wasn´t able to transfer this syntax to Python. Instead I iterated over the Threshold (p x 1) vector:

```
def histo(VecIn, ThreshLow, Var1): 
   
    # create upper limits
    ThreshHigh=np.append(ThreshLow[1:],1e5)
    
    # iterate over ThreshLow (i to p)
    histVar1 = []
    for i in range (0, len(LowThresh)):
        # create n x 1 boolean mask
        mask = (v >= LowThresh[i]) & (v < ThreshHigh[i])
        histVar1.append(np.sum(Var1[mask]))

    return np.array(histVar1)
```

The upper examples both work for me, but I am looking for a concise (and possibly fast) code alternative. Maybe there are even more efficient ways to write such a function or maybe such a function is part of a common library.

Comment: Why did you opt for the for loop in python? You can pretty much translate your matlab code 1:1 to numpy, without having to introduce the loop.

Comment: is `Var1` really `n`-by-1? `Var1(mask)` throws an indexing error on my end